# Integer Exponentiation

Tags: c#

**Implementation:**

This works based on this observation:

$$a^n = a^{n/2} * a^{n/2}$$

```
BigInteger Pow(BigInteger x,int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    else if(n % 2 == 0) {
        var val = Pow(x,n/2);
        return val * val;
    }
    else return x * Pow(x,n-1);
}
```

How can I improve this? Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: You can skip the `else` and just keep the `return x * Pow(x,n-1);` And pleeeease allow the method parameters to breath so your code is more readable.

Comment: Why don't you use BigInteger.Pow static method?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You could use a loop instead of recursion, but given that most of the work will be done in the calculations, there isn't much point in optimising that.

Comment: BigInteger has a property IsEven, so you don't need the n % 2

Comment: There's an infinite loop if n=-1. Should probably just error for negative n.

Comment: I don't know enough to say for sure, but I'm guessing there's an `O(1)` algorithm for finding exponents?

Comment: See [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 6):

- Don't use Egyptian style bracing, that is the style more widely accepted by Java, use the more widely accepted C# bracing style.

Your current structure for the if/else statements is not good.  If you have to use braces in the else/elseif statements then you should use bracing everywhere, even on a single operation inside the if statement

like this

```
BigInteger Pow(BigInteger x,int n)
{
    if(n == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        var val = Pow(x,n/2);
        return val * val;
    }
    else
    {
        return x * Pow(x,n-1);
    }
}
```

---

Use if statements like this without the else if

```
BigInteger Pow(BigInteger x,int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        var val = Pow(x,n/2);
        return val * val;
    }
    return x * Pow(x,n-1);
}
```

You return inside the if statements so there is no need to else anything just if through because if the first one is true then none of the other if statements will be executed.

---

I needed to change `BigInteger` to `long`. `BigInteger` it still an INT and so is `long`, for some reason I could not use `BigInteger`, so in my equations I will use `long`

Your naming should definitely be better I went with `numBase` and `numPower` I don't normally like hungarian style notation like this, but `base` is kind of reserved and all.

this is what mine looks like

```
public static long Pow(long numBase, long numPower)
{
    if (numPower == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (numPower % 2 == 0)
    {
        var val = Pow(numBase, numPower / 2);
        return val * val;
    }
    return numBase * Pow(numBase, numPower - 1);
}
```

also I went with a static method inside of a static class so I could just call it willy-nilly whenever I felt like it.  Like this:

```
Class1.Pow(numBase,numPower);
```

the only thing with this is that it looks like you are overloading the already created `Math.Pow` method, you should probably at the least Comment to that effect, and/or create an actual overload for `Math.Pow`

Comment: The C# syntax doesn't specify how you should place braces. You can advocate any style you like, but it's not "C# syntax".

Comment: @Guffa is that better?

Comment: Not really. There is nothing unacceptable about either style.

Comment: @Guffa, the Egyptian style of bracing is widely accepted as the Java bracing style, where the other style is widely accepted as C# bracing style.

Comment: That is simply not true, there isn't a bracing style that is identified as "C# bracing style".

Comment: let's get the General consensus from Chat, there are others that would support my view and they would probably have better reasons as well, [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: Just search for questions about it, and you will find that there are always answers suggesting both styles. There is no style that is said to be the only accepted one.

Comment: When in Rome do as the Romans @Guffa. C# devs expect their braces a certain way. While consistency within a code base is more important than conforming to a particular style, it certainly is nice to write code that peers are comfortable with.

Comment: Here's some corner cases: `Pow(0, 0)`, `Pow(2, -2)`

Comment: I will have to double check that when I get home, but I think that at the least `Pow(0,0)` will be caught by `if (numPower == 0)` and the other one looks like it may get caught in an infinite decrementation loop, but I will have to verify later

Comment: @RubberDuck: If C# developers actually did expect their braces in a certain way, then there would be a consensus about what that way would be. That doesn't exist.

Comment: Brace style is IMHO an entirely stylistic issue.  So long as the code is _consistently_ braced then you should concentrate on the _content_ and not the _style_.

Comment: System.Numerics.BigInteger is an arbitrarily large integer.  long is a primitive for storing integers in the range –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  These two are not the same, for example the BigInteger does not overrun.

Comment: @Taemyr I edited my answer, now that you mention that I remember reading that somewhere, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Malachi's coding style suggestions. While you can customize Visual Studio to make up your own styling convention in a very flexible way, I find it better when people adapts to the language's most used / popular styling conventions for mainly two reasons:

1. Your code formatting will homogeneous among all your projects by default;
2. The code you post on Q&A websites and forums will not get criticized about the formatting and people reformatting your code for lisibility on these websites will not have an hard time doing it.

There is actually a C# coding style used by most developers at Microsoft and it has a long [history](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=A%20Brief%20History%20of%20CSharp%20Style&referringTitle=Documentation):

The main idea behind this style is to ensure **consistency**.

When you enforce braces on their own line everywhere (in method blocks, conditional blocks, etc.) it becomes easier and quicker to read and understand, for everybody.

I bet you would be quickly criticized by most Java developers if you were posting Java code without the Egyptian braces style. Every language has its founding coding conventions.

Comment: Egyption-style bracing essentially compels the use of a brace-pair for all conditionals, even those which control only a single statement, while open-brace-on-own-line style makes it much safer to have a conditional control a single statement. Effectively, then, Egyptian-style saves a line every time a control statement affects multiple statements, but costs a line in many cases where a conditional affects just one statement.

Comment: I didn't mean that a style is better than another. My point is it's better to stick to the original coding convention of that language. And above all, don't mix coding conventions throughout the same code base.

Comment: There is no original coding convention for C#. The automatic formatting was introduced in VS 2008, when people had been writing C# code for five years already.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using iteration instead of recursion. Here's an example with short variable names (p for power, b for base, r for result) and compact if statements (to make code easier to read).

Boolean array in first loop keeps track of what kind of multiplication to apply in the second loop. Using long allows for results up to 10^18 (or 2^62) before overflowing.

```
public static long Pow(int b, int p)
{
    if (p < 0) return -1;   // p must be positive
    if (p == 0) return 1;

    bool[] a = new bool[p/2 + 2];
    int i = -1;
    while (p > 0)
    {
        if (p % 2 == 0) { a[++i] = true;  p /= 2; }
        else            { a[++i] = false; p--;    }             
    }

    long r = b;
    while (i-- > 0)
    {
        if (a[i]) { r *= r; }
        else      { r *= b; }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Adding less optimal single loop iterative code example for comparison as mentioned in comments. In case of 2^15 Pow does 6 multiplications and PowUp does 10.

```
public static long PowUp(int b, int p) // not optimal
{
    if (p < 0) return -1;   // p must be positive
    if (p == 0) return 1;

    long r = b;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < p) 
    {
        if (i * 2 < p) { r *= r; i *= 2; }
        else           { r *= b; i++;    }              
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Allocating a new array to calculate pow seems "excessive". There's no need for that even in an iterative form.

Comment: Iterative form with a single loop is less effective as it requires more steps between p/2 and p. 2^15 requires only 6 multiplications using code above and 10 multiplications in case of single loop implementation (see PowUp method above).

Comment: Except you're not counting the 5 divisions and 5 mod operations in the first case - which brings the operation count back to about par. And then the array allocation would usually completely dwarf all of that anyway. (Depends on whether the compiler can optimize the allocation away entirely...)

Comment: Agreed. It starts to make a difference for bigger powers [O(logN) vs. O(N)].